# Writing VBA code for finding geometric mean

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a custom VBA function that calculates the geometric mean. I know there is a worksheet function already but I am trying to write this on my own. Geometric Mean = nth root of multiple of n numbers.

For example: Assume you have the following 2 numbers in excel column: 2, 8

Geometric Mean = (2*8)^(1/n); n = 2, since there are 2 numbers, 2 and 8. 
so, geometric mean = (2*8)^(1/2)=16^(1/2) = 4

So I have to write a simple VBA-excel code/function to find the geometric mean of any set of numbers in an excel column. I wrote a code but it doesn't give me the correct answers, could you please help me to correct it?

```
Option Explicit
Function Geometric(rs)
Dim Sum as single
Dim i As Integer
Dim n As Integer
n = rs.Count
For i = 1 To n
sum = sum + (rs(i)) ^ (1 / n)
Next i
Geometric = sum
End Function
```

Comment: how do you want to use the function? what is rs?

Comment: Um, why not use GEOMEAN()?  I know it is available on Office 365 Excel, maybe not on older versions?

Comment: It is available since Excel 2007, https://support.office.com/en-us/article/geomean-function-db1ac48d-25a5-40a0-ab83-0b38980e40d5

Comment: See my second comment, are you using older than 2007?

Comment: @ScottCraner `" I know there is a worksheet function already but I am trying to write this on my own"` from the question

Comment: Yes, and qn is more on whats wrong with the above fn.

Comment: Can you give an example of an incorrect input and output? Continually raising to a fractional power in a loop makes me suspect that you don't have enough precision in a `Single`.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 who has time to read?  My bad.  Felt bad so answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will account for different types of inputs (I called the input `arg_vNumbers` instead of `rs`) and also only processes for inputs that are actually numbers, so it will ignore text, etc):

```
Public Function GEOMETRICMEAN(ByVal arg_vNumbers As Variant) As Variant

    Dim rConstants As Range
    Dim rFormulas As Range
    Dim rAdjusted As Range
    Dim vElement As Variant
    Dim lTotalElements As Long
    Dim dProductTotal As Double

    Select Case TypeName(arg_vNumbers)
        Case "Range"
            If arg_vNumbers.Rows.Count = arg_vNumbers.Parent.Rows.Count Then
                Set rAdjusted = Intersect(arg_vNumbers.Parent.UsedRange, arg_vNumbers)
            Else
                Set rAdjusted = arg_vNumbers
            End If
            On Error Resume Next
            Set rConstants = rAdjusted.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers)
            Set rFormulas = rAdjusted.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlNumbers)
            On Error GoTo 0
            Select Case Abs((rConstants Is Nothing) + 2 * (rFormulas Is Nothing))
                Case 0: Set rAdjusted = Union(rConstants, rFormulas)
                Case 1: Set rAdjusted = rFormulas
                Case 2: Set rAdjusted = rConstants
                Case 3: GEOMETRICMEAN = CVErr(xlErrDiv0)
                        Exit Function
            End Select

            For Each vElement In rAdjusted
                If IsNumeric(vElement) And Len(vElement) > 0 Then
                    lTotalElements = lTotalElements + 1
                    If lTotalElements = 1 Then
                        dProductTotal = vElement
                    Else
                        dProductTotal = dProductTotal * vElement
                    End If
                End If
            Next vElement
            If lTotalElements > 0 Then
                GEOMETRICMEAN = dProductTotal ^ (1 / lTotalElements)
            Else
                GEOMETRICMEAN = CVErr(xlErrDiv0)
            End If

        Case "Variant()", "Collection", "Dictionary"
            For Each vElement In arg_vNumbers
                If IsNumeric(vElement) Then
                    lTotalElements = lTotalElements + 1
                    If lTotalElements = 1 Then
                        dProductTotal = vElement
                    Else
                        dProductTotal = dProductTotal * vElement
                    End If
                End If
            Next vElement
            If lTotalElements > 0 Then
                GEOMETRICMEAN = dProductTotal ^ (1 / lTotalElements)
            Else
                GEOMETRICMEAN = CVErr(xlErrDiv0)
            End If

        Case Else
            If IsNumeric(arg_vNumbers) Then
                GEOMETRICMEAN = arg_vNumbers
            Else
                GEOMETRICMEAN = CVErr(xlErrDiv0)
            End If

    End Select

End Function
```

The advantage to this is that it can also accept user defined arrays as part of a worksheet formula, for example: `=GEOMETRICMEAN({2,8})` in addition to accepting a range of numbers.  It can also accept VBA arrays, Collections and Dictionaries and will process only the numeric portions of those objects.  If no numbers are included anywhere in the input, it returns a `#DIV/0!` error.

These allowances and error handling cause this UDF to behave pretty closely to how the built-in `GEOMEAN` function does.

Answer (score 2):

No loop needed just use `Application.Product`

```
Function Geometric(rs As Range)
    Dim Sum As Double
    Dim n As Long
    n = rs.Count

    Sum = Application.Product(rs) ^ (1 / n)

    Geometric = Sum
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You formula was wrong, use this:

```
Option Explicit
Function Geometric(rs as range)
    Dim dGM As Double
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    n = rs.Count
    dGM = 1
    For i = 1 To n
        dGM = dGM * rs(i)
    Next i

    Geometric = dGM ^ (1 / n)

End Function
```

Comment: you can use `application.product` too, but it depends how you want to use the range where there are you data